# Validate and store data in Laravel with axios

Tags: json, laravel, axios

I am using React\NextJS as forntend and Laravel as backend,
Storing data with Axios post as per below,

```
  const storeExpense = async (expenseData) => {

    const response = await axios.post('/api/expenses/store/', {expenseData})
    return response.data;
  }
```

Now this will be sent as a JSON object to Laravel, **I am not sure how can I validate and store this JSON object data to MySQL.**

Earlier I was using Jquery AJAX where it was easy to store with Request validation and then with create.

Below is the request payload to the backend,

```
{"expenseData":{"expense_description":"React","expense_date":"2022-17-4","expense_amount":"123","expense_tax_amount":"14.15","expense_note":"given","expense_receipt_number":"Ok no","taxgroup_id":1,"paymentoption_id":1,"vendor_id":1,"accountcustomtype_id":2,"submit":null}}
```

Below was Controller and Model, used when sending data as Form

```
     //Controller
    public function store(StoreExpenseRequest $request)
    {
        Expense::storeExpense($request);

        return response()->json([
            'val' => 1,
            'msg' => 'Success',
        ]);
    }

    //Model
    public static function storeExpense($request)
    {
        Expense::create([
            'vendor_id' => $request->vendor_id,
            'accountcustomtype_id' => $request->accountcustomtype_id,
            'expense_description' => $request->expense_description,
            'expense_date' => Carbon::parse($request->expense_date)->format('Y-m-d'),
            'expense_amount' => $request->expense_amount,
            'taxgroup_id' => $request->taxgroup_id,
            'expense_tax_amount' => $request->expense_tax_amount,
            'paymentoption_id' => $request->paymentoption_id,
            'expense_receipt_number' => $request->expense_receipt_number,
            'expense_note' => $request->expense_note,
        ]);
    }
```

But now this doesn't work with JSON data,

How can I achieve this with Axios JSON data?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved by changing Axios request Data,

```
await axios.post('/api/expenses/store/', expenseData)
```